# How to merge the two different files after the file is renamed

Tags: git

I create a file `foo` in the git repository on branch `master`.

Then, I create a new branch `dev`, using `git checkout -b dev`.

On the branch `dev`, I rename it to `bar` using `git mv foo bar`.

After that, I change something in the `foo` and commit it.

But, when I checkout branch `dev` and `git merge master`, **git** doesn't merge it automatically for me and asks me to merge it myself.

So, is `foo` the ancestor of `bar` after I execute `git mv`? Is there any way to let **git** merge automatically?

Comment: `foo` is not an ancestor of `bar` because git doesn't track renames, it tracks only file content.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try ```hg```, since it supports tracking renames. @wRAR

Comment: @wrar It may not track renames but `git-merge-recursive` will certainly detect them by similarity with the ancestor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in "[git merge with renamed files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2701790/git-merge-with-renamed-files)", you should try and adapt the rename threshold:

> Since git 1.7.4, you can specify the rename threshold for merge as

```
git merge -X rename-threshold=25
```

> in order to control that a similarity of 25% is already enough to consider two files rename candidates.
>   This, depending on the case together with `-X ignore-space-change` may make rename detection more reliable.

Still from [Tilman Vogel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119725/tilman-vogel), the script [`git-merge-associate`](https://gist.github.com/tvogel/894374) can help restore the association between two files (one being the renamed version of the other), when the merge doesn't detect the rename.