# How can git ignore move during a merge?

Tags: git, git-merge

In a feature branch we moved one directory (it was commited as file move not delete / creation). Before merging my branch on master, I merge master on it.

When doing "git merge master", the files appears on the old location as untracked and on the new location the file doesn't have the changes from master.

Any idea if I can fix this without manual merging ?

Comment: Did git mention a conflict when you tried to merge ?

Comment: No conflict on those files :(

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/q/2701790/1256452 - note that Git *detects* renames. It does not *record* them, it just guesses later.